# Writing to existing xlsm files

Tags: openpyxl

[image: Print screen from openpyxl documentation]

Given the documentation above, does this mean it is not possible to write to an existing `.xlsm` file, not modifying previously existent information?

Comment: What do you mean? If you want to modify a file you need to open it, modify it, and save it back. This warning simply means that doing `wb.save("file.xlsx")` will save `wb` to `file.xlsx`. If the file exists already it will be overriden without a warning. This is similar to doing `file = open("file.txt", 'w')`. If `file.txt` exists, it will be truncated...

Comment: Thanks for your comments @ Tomerikoo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it means that if there is a file with the same name, it will not warn you, it will just replace the file.

You can modify existing excel files, however, it doesn't save modifications, rather it overwrites the old file with a new file with modifications.